# Improve NFS performance for Windows NFS client to Linux NFS Server

Tags: windows-7, nfs

I have a CentOS 6.7 server as an NFS Server, and I have a 3-4  Windows 7 (Enterprise) PC's using Windows NFS client to mount the NFS exports.

The problem I'm having is this:

The Windows clients can mount the NFS share just fine. However after a certain period of idle time, the next time I try and use the share (by clicking on the drive letter) there is a significant delay (about 10 seconds or so) before the share becomes responsive.

Are there NFS export options or client settings I can change to keep the connection alive for longer?

Comment: (You could use Samba)

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. However there is a reason I'm using NFS.

Comment: Is your DNS working? Try putting the hostname of the NFS server in the hosts file. And I would run a tcpdump to see if packets arrive at the beginning of the delay or at the end at the server. If it is at the end, then the problem is on the client.

Comment: Having same issue in Windows 10.

Answer (score -1):

http://veerapen.blogspot.com/2011/09/tuning-redhat-enterprise-linux-rhel-54.html

Configuring the Linux scheduler on systems with hardware RAID and changing the default from [cfq] to [noop] gives I/O improvements.

Use the nfsstat command, to calculate percentage of reads/writes. Set the RAID controller cache ratio to match.

For heavy workloads you will need to increase the number of NFS server threads.

Configure the nfs threads to write without delay to the disk using the no_delay option.

Tell the Linux kernel to flush as quickly as possible so that writes are kept as small as possible. In the Linux kernel, dirty pages writeback frequency can be controlled by two parameters.

For faster disk writes, use the filesystem data=journal option and prevent updates to file access times which in itself results in additional data written to the disk. This mode is the fastest when data needs to be read from and written to disk at the same time where it outperforms all other modes